# Microsoft Report Viewer to show parent/child data such as invoices headers followed by invoice details

Tags: vb.net, report, rdlc, subreport, report-viewer2010

After several hours of searching the internet I could not find any Report Viewer tutorials that show a project that contains a parent/child report.

I'm using rdlc report files.

I can create a single report but we want to create a report that shows shows invoice header information followed by the invoice details followed by the next invoice header and details and so on.

Can you direct us to a simple sample project that demonstrates this technique?

If a sample project is not available, do you know of an online tutorial that shows how to do it?

I saw something that might help on gotreportviewer.com about subreports, but it's in C# and not VB.Net so I could not figure out how it works.

Answer (score 0):

There are many samples on CodeProject.... Have you looked at these?

- [Grouping](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15055/Dynamic-Data-Grouping-using-Microsoft-Reporting-Se)
- [Advanced Report Viewer](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35225/Advanced-Report-Viewer)
- [Creating Reports with SQL Reporting Service](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6999/Creating-Reports-with-SQL-Reporting-Service-and-Vi)

Comment: Thanks for the links. I looked at them but I'm not familiar with SQL Server Reporting Services and the code is in C# which I also don't know. Is there something like these in VB.Net and also using the Microsoft Report Viewer? I'm using rdlc report files.